# Difference between collect and as.data.frame in sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

What is the difference between `as.data.frame()` and `collect()`, when heaving a DataFrame object into local memory?

Comment: `str` returns the same for both in my output and `identical` returns `TRUE`

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference whatsoever. Excluding argument validation `Sparkr::as.data.frame` is [simply implemented](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/R/pkg/R/DataFrame.R#L2276-L2284) with a single call to `SparkR::collect`:

```
setMethod("as.data.frame",
          signature(x = "DataFrame"),
          function(x, ...) {
             # Arguments validation      
          }
          collect(x)
        })
```